# Load multiple images on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, button, uiimageview

So I have a UIButton, when said button is pressed a UIView is created which holds 10 UIImageViews, all of those have a size of 100x100. For every UIImageView there's an image with the size of 640x960, which I resize to fit the UIImageView. My problem is that every time I press the button there's a 1-2 second delay before the UIView gets created, but everything works fine if I remove the UIImageViews. Can anyone provide some help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading and resizing 10 UIImageViews is going to cause delay. Create thumbnail versions of your images by pre-resizing them to 100x100 and load them instead of the large ones and there should be minimal delay.